# Unable to mock NestJS Guard's dependencies in test

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, nestjs

I've recently started learning NestJS and wanted to develop a small project in it to get some hands-on experience, but I've been having issues in testing an `AuthenticationGuard` I created. More specifically, I've tried to mock one of its dependencies in many different ways, but it doesn't seem to work.

Let me be more specific. I have an `AuthenticationGuard`, which has a dependency on `SessionService`. `AuthenticationGuard` merely checks the HTTP request header for a custom field which holds the session id and validates it using `SessionService`. If it's valid, then the request can pass. The problem is, when setting up my tests, I can't properly mock `SessionService` in order to test the case when the requests should go through, and I keep getting a 401 HTTP error (which is thrown when the validation fails).

I'll paste the code for `AuthenticationGuard`, `SessionService` and for the test below.

My hunch is that I'm missing something really stupid that I might've skipped on the documentation, but I can't figure out what it is. Any guesses? Any help is much appreciated.

```js
// session.service.ts
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Employee } from '../employee/employee.entity';
import { EmployeeSession } from './types';
import * as uid from 'uid-safe';

// An in-memory session service, for simplicity purposes.
// Needs to deal with dangling sessions!
@Injectable()
export class SessionService {
  private sessions: Map<string, EmployeeSession> = new Map();
  public createEmployeeSession(employee: Employee) {
    const sessionId = uid.sync(24);
    this.sessions.set(sessionId, {
      employeeId: employee.id,
      expiresAt: new Date(Date.now() + 1000 * 60 * 60 * 8), // 8 hours
    });
    return sessionId;
  }
  public getEmployeeSession(sessionId: string): EmployeeSession | null {
    const session = this.sessions.get(sessionId);
    if (session === undefined) return null;
    if (session.expiresAt.getTime() <= Date.now()) {
      this.sessions.delete(sessionId);
      return null;
    }
    return session;
  }
}

// authentication.guard.ts
import {
  CanActivate,
  ExecutionContext,
  Injectable,
  UnauthorizedException,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private sessionService: SessionService) {}
  canActivate(
    context: ExecutionContext,
  ): boolean | Promise<boolean> | Observable<boolean> {
    const request = context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
    const starlightSessionId = request.headers['STARLIGHT_SESSION_ID'];
    if (typeof starlightSessionId !== 'string')
      throw new UnauthorizedException('Authentication failed!');
    const session = this.sessionService.getEmployeeSession(starlightSessionId);
    if (!session) throw new UnauthorizedException('Authentication failed!');
    return true;
  }
}

// authentication.guard.spec.ts
import {
  Controller,
  Get,
  HttpStatus,
  INestApplication,
  Provider,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthenticationGuard } from './authentication.guard';
import { SessionService } from './session.service';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { APP_GUARD } from '@nestjs/core';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import mockEmployee from '../employee/employee.stub';

const RETURN_VALUE = 'test';
@Controller('test')
class TestController {
  @Get()
  test() {
    return RETURN_VALUE;
  }
}

describe('AuthenticationGuard', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  afterEach(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });

  it('should throw error when session id is not provided', async () => {
    app = await createApp(SessionService);
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/test')
      .expect(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  });

  it('should throw when session with session id does not exist', async () => {
    app = await createApp(SessionService);
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/test')
      .set('STARLIGHT_SESSION_ID', 'gibberish')
      .expect(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
  });

  it.only('should let pass when session id is valid', async () => {
    const sessionService: SessionService = new SessionService();
    // I also attempted to use jest.spyOn here, but it also didn't work.
    const sessionId = sessionService.createEmployeeSession(mockEmployee);
    app = await createApp({
      provide: SessionService,
      useValue: sessionService,
    });
    return request(app.getHttpServer())
      .get('/test')
      .set('STARLIGHT_SESSION_ID', sessionId)
      .expect(HttpStatus.OK, RETURN_VALUE);
  });
});

async function createApp(sessionServiceProvider: Provider) {
  const app = (
    await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [TestController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_GUARD,
          useClass: AuthenticationGuard,
        },
        sessionServiceProvider,
      ],
    }).compile()
  ).createNestApplication();
  app.init();
  return app;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I came back to this after lunch and managed to figure it out. As I expected, it was something dumb that I was overlooking.

The error was not on the test, it was on the `AuthenticationGuard` itself. I was accessing the `request.headers` field wrong. I was trying to access it with `STARLIGHT_SESSION_ID`, while it should be `starlight_session_id` (all lowercase). After changing it, all tests passed.